# switch graphic card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and it is wonderful. I am faced with a small problem though: 
I have two graphic cards, one is the native Nvidia Gforce 8600 M GT and the other is a Geforce GTX 260 (connected by viadock) when I list the drivers I found only the 8600gt. is there anyway to switch to the exteral or activate them both ?

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84M [GeForce 8600M GT] (rev a1)
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT200 [GeForce GTX 260] (rev a1)
```

All the best !